# I am trying to create an embed but it keeps giving me an invalid syntax with the variable name

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Here is my code and bits of it above since someone asked. The modules/packages used are discord and os.

```
#Settings Embed
Settings = discord.Embed(title=("Settings"), description=("Here you can change bot settings for your server."), color=EE0000FF)
Settings.add_field(name=("Enter 1 to change bot prefix"), value= ("Current bot prefix: {prefix}").format(prefix), inline=False)
Settings.add_field(name=("Enter 2 to change bot moderator role"), value=(""""Current bot moderator role: {bot_mod_role_name}
(**BY DEFAULT THIS OPTION IS SET TO THE BOT\'S ROLE.)
PLEASE CREATE A ROLE AND ASSIGN IT TO THIS VALUE!**)""").format(bot_mod_role_name=get_role(bot_mod_role_id), inline=False)


#Settings Lack Permissions Embed
SettingsLackPermissions = discord.Embed(title=("You do not have the required permissions to use this command"), color=EE0000FF)
SettingsLackPermissions.add_field(name=("You must either be the owner of this guild or have the bot moderator role which is {bot_mod_role_name}").format(bot_mod_role_name=get_role(bot_mod_role_id)), inline=False)
```

Here is the error I received:

```
  File "c:\Users\ttuser\Desktop\bot\main.py", line 25
    SettingsLackPermissions = discord.Embed(title=("You do not have the required permissions to use this command"), color=EE0000FF)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Could you show the line directly before/above this line of code please?

Comment: Just added the above.

Comment: Note that there is no need to put parentheses around strings – strings are already delimited by their quotes. For example, ``title=("Settings")`` should just be ``title="Settings"``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
value=(""""Current bot moderator role: {bot_mod_role_name}(**BY DEFAULT THIS OPTION IS SET TO THE BOT\'S ROLE.) PLEASE CREATE A ROLE AND ASSIGN IT TO THIS VALUE!**)""")
```

In this bit here, you've got 4 front quotes (") and 3 back quotes. The code thinks that it's still a string.
I'm not entirely sure why you'd put a comment inside of there? I'd recommend balancing the number of quotes and trying again.

```
.format(bot_mod_role_name=get_role(bot_mod_role_id), inline=False)
```

This line also has an issue with syntax. You've got a missing bracket on the format function. Fixed code would be

```
.format(bot_mod_role_name=get_role(bot_mod_role_id)), inline=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for informing me about this, but that's the solution to another issue, and the issue stated in the post still persists.

Comment: I noticed you've got another issue with brackets. @muffinguy I edited my post to reflect it.

Comment: The opening ``""""`` is a triple-quote followed by a literal quote *string*. Compare ``print("""" """)``; it's likely unintentional but not a syntax error.